# How to style a Firebase Google sign-in button

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-signin

I have a working link for signing in to a Google account in javascript ([using Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)):

```
<a onClick={customFirebaseGoogleLogin}>Login</a>
```

How can I make the link look like a standard [Google Sign-In Button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)?

Here's their button (with the dependencies):

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

I want to replace the built in functionality that comes with their button. Currently, when the button is clicked it takes the user to sign in, but I don't need that, I have Firebase handling my sign in flow.

Note that the standard button also follows wether the user is signed in or not and changes accordingly. It also gives me a console warning ("Not a valid origin for the client..."). I want to remove all of this functionality or perhaps connect it to the firebase sign in status instead. All I really want from this button is the standard design.

Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this?